# How come I cannot perform multiple keystore cipher decryptions on Samsung S6 and S7?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-keystore

I have found an issue that appears to be affecting some Samsung(so far) devices only.
Here is the sudo:

- initialize cipher1 and cipher2
- decrypt using cipher1
- decrypt using cipher2

IllegalBlockSizeException

Basically if I am holding on to one cipher, while decryption another in between trying to decrypt the other, we receive the exception.

We tried on a Nexus 6P, Nexus 5X, Note 4 (No issue)
We saw the issue on (S7, S7 Edge, S6)

Code:

```
public void createKey(String keyName) {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = null;
        try {
            generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                keyName,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                .build();
        try {
            generator.initialize(spec);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }

        generator.generateKeyPair();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createKey("Key");
        createKey("Key1");

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("Key", null);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();

        Cipher c;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        } else {
            c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        }
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        mCancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();



        String ecryptedS1 = doEncription("Key1");
        KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks1.load(null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry1 = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks1.getEntry("Key1", null);
        PrivateKey privateKey1 = (PrivateKey) privateKeyEntry1.getPrivateKey();

        Cipher c1;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            c1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        } else {
            c1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        }
        c1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey1);

        String org = "";
        try {
            org = new String(c1.doFinal(Base64.decode(ecryptedS1, Base64.DEFAULT|Base64.NO_WRAP)));
            Log.d("MainActivity", "org key1" + org);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        org = null;
        try {
            org = new String(c.doFinal(Base64.decode(doEncription("Key"), Base64.DEFAULT|Base64.NO_WRAP)));
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
10-04 14:29:13.919 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:486)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1502)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at com.example.rollandliu.decryption.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:248)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10885)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22533)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
10-04 14:29:13.929 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err: Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid operation handle
10-04 14:29:13.939 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:940)
10-04 14:29:13.939 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:132)
10-04 14:29:13.939 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:217)
10-04 14:29:13.939 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:473)
10-04 14:29:13.939 15568-15568/com.example.rollandliu.decryption W/System.err:     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Post your (relevant) code here. We do not go "outside" to download it.

Comment: Code posted, thanks

Answer (score 11):

It's a little outdated, but I'll post an answer here just in case some good folk will be trying to solve that problem.

Samsung devices have different implementation of `Cipher` class running in their JVM and in my case I only had to make operations with it `synchronized`.

It solved issue for me, so I may take a guess that Samsung's `Cipher` is not thread safe.
Cheers!